# Protecting Android debug bridge that is connected to the internet

Tags: android, smartphone

I have an android device which acts as a brain for my home security that has access to cameras, heat sensors, motion sensors and some appliances.

I have enabled android debug bridge on my android device so I can send commands if I am away from home, like querying my motion sensors.

How can I  add a level of security for my android device which is left exposed to the internet?

Comment: Just to confirm we are on the same page: you have enabled adb over tcp and made connections to it possible from the internet?

Comment: yes correct because I need to send adb shell command over the internet

Answer (score 2):

You basically have a powerful debug service without authentication listening on TCP port exposed to the internet.

**Don't expose it to internet**

Do not just put it on the internet. Put it behind a firewall (I guess just plain home router NAT would also count) and set up VPN (or ssh tunnel or similar) so only authorised people can connect.

**Put it behind a firewall**

Above option is preferred, but this might be acceptable to you as well (but is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks).

a) Configure firewall to only allow connections from specific IPs

b) Use port knocking

Comment: thanks @domen, right now I can only do option 2 since the router I have is controlled by my ISP and they remotely reset configuration periodically